# Specific data in array from object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have data like,

```
const data = {
    pizza: ['Pizza Margherita', 'peppy paneer'],
    sandwich: [],
    burger: ['Veg Maharaja'],
    number: [0,2]
};
```

I want to store data in the form of an array,

```
[ 'Pizza Margherita', 'peppy paneer','Veg Maharaja' ]
```

This is what I tried,

```
const food = [];
for(key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const element = data[key];
        element.forEach(el => {
            food.push(el)
        });
    }
}
//It Gives output like [ 'Pizza Margherita', 'peppy paneer', 'Veg Maharaja', 0, 2 ]
```

but I want to ignore last key number.

Comment: how do you know if it's an array of the variables you want to keep ?

Comment: `but I want to ignore last key number` So the object's structure is uncertain? Or do you just want to add strings only?

Comment: @CertainPerformance strings only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert the object into an array by using `Object.values` You can flatten the array by using `concat` and spread syntax. Use `filter` to get only the string.

```js
const data = {
  pizza: ['Pizza Margherita', 'peppy paneer'],
  sandwich: [],
  burger: ['Veg Maharaja'],
  number: [0, 2]
};

const result = [].concat(...Object.values(data)).filter(isNaN);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply exclude that key named as `number`

```js
const data = {
    pizza: ['Pizza Margherita', 'peppy paneer'],
    sandwich: [],
    burger: ['Veg Maharaja'],
    number: [0,2]
};

const food = [];
for(key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key) && key!='number') {
        const element = data[key];
        element.forEach(el => {
            food.push(el)
        });
    }
}

console.log(food)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put a condition to avoid iteration over the `number` key values.

```js
const data = {
    pizza: ['Pizza Margherita', 'peppy paneer'],
    sandwich: [],
    burger: ['Veg Maharaja'],
    number: [0,2]
};

const food = [];
for(key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const element = data[key];
        if(key !== 'number'){
        element.forEach(el => {
            food.push(el)
        });
        }
        
    }
}

console.log(food)
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does in order to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old fashioned way, but the result is what you expected.

```js
var data = {
    pizza: ['Pizza Margherita', 'peppy paneer'],
    sandwich: [],
    burger: ['Veg Maharaja'],
    number: [0,2]
};

var food = [];
for(key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const element = data[key];
        element.forEach(el => {
            if(typeof el=='string') food.push(el)
        });
    }
}

console.log(food)
```